# How to apply command to all elements of a list?

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, map

So I generated a list of cities and I want to apply FindGeoLocation to all of them without having to seperate the elements and then applying.

```
y= CityData[{Large, Last[x]}]
```

(x here is dynamically updated from

```
x = RandomChoice[CountryData[]]]

TextString@y
```

Gives me a list of the Cities.

But now I want to take the list and have FindGeoLocation evaluate it at all the given cities in the list.

As far as I know, Map does that with functions. I don't know what to do next.

Comment: FindGeoLocation works directly with entities. So why are you converting to strings ? FindGeoLocation[RandomChoice[CountryData[]]] works directly.

Comment: does `#["Position"] & /@ y` give what you need?

Comment: What about `Map`?